# Can't get query parameter from email sent by GMail API

Tags: php, gmail, base64, mime

the php code for sending email:

```
$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($mime);
$objSentMsg = $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
```

$strRawMessage contains a url
`http://localhost/gmail/index.php?user=abc`,
when received the email, the url is 
`http://localhost/gmail/index.php?userabc`,
missing '=' after '?user', how to solve this? Thanks.